# How to create an azure repository directly from git bash command line? (without entering the browser)

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, repository, azure-cli

**Update**

I am trying to create a repository from git bash command line to AzureDevops team platform,

I've been following these instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-cmdline?view=azure-devops

I am having trouble with the prerequisites, I ran the next lines:

```
az --version                          # version is greater than v2.0.49
az extension add --name azure-devops  # no problem with this line 
az devops login --organization org_url 
PAT                                   # problem arises here....
```

The next line arises after running end line:

`Failed to authenticate using the supplied token.`

I am creating the PAT by following these instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

Do I have to ask for manager credentials or else what could I do to solve this issue?

Comment: replace `az` with `az.cmd` and retry

Comment: do you have the azure CLI tools installed? What happens when you run `az --version`?

Comment: I already installed Azure CLI it says ```azure-cli  2.16.0 ```

Comment: Can you get the existing repos in your DevOps? It means you can run the command `az repos list` and get the right output.

Comment: Hey @Charles Xu, I can't as `az login` runs with fail...

Comment: Do you mean you cannot use the Azure CLI in git bash? Or just cannot log in?

Comment: I cannot use the Azure CLI in git bash

Comment: Any more updates on this question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

From the error message, you probably need to [install the Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli). You must have at least `v2.0.49`, which you can verify with `az --version` command. Then you can run the `az login` command to login with your Azure account.

### Update

Just follow the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/share-your-code-in-git-cmdline?view=azure-devops). You can do the steps in your git bash or other terminals:

1. Download and install Azure CLI and add Azure DevOps extension.

```
   az extension add --name azure-devops
   az login #login in with your Azure account
   az devops configure --defaults organization=https://dev.azure.com/contoso project=contoso
```

2. Create a local Git repo for your code. If your code is already in a local Git repo, you can skip this step.

```
cd /home/fabrikam/fiber
git init .
git add --all
git commit -m "first commit of my code"
```

3. Create a new Git repo in Azure Repos and connect your local repo to the Git repo in Azure Repos using `remoteUrl` in the response from your creating Git repo :

```
az repos create --name  mywebapprepos
git remote add origin https://xxx.xxx.com/webapp-test/_git/mywebapprepos
```

[image]

4. Before pushing your code, you need to login in with your Azure account to authenticate. For me, it will prompt the Windows UI to login in with my account.

```
git push origin master
```

[image]

Comment: and after that how could I push the repo to AzureDevops from Azure CLI terminal? , ```az --version``` is ```2.16.0```

Comment: So, is the error "bash: az: command not found" still exist?

Comment: After that, before pushing your code, you need to set up authentication with [credential managers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-up-credential-managers?view=azure-devops) or [SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops) before continuing.

Comment: When I run `az repos create --name demo_repo` it returns the following message: ```Before you can run Azure DevOps commands, you need to run the login command(az login if using AAD/MSA identity else az devops login if using PAT token) to setup credentials.  Please see https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth for more information```

Comment: Then I run ```az devops login```and it runs fine, however when I reran ```az repos create --name demo_repo``` it returns me error 404 not found; as well I tried to find SSH keys and there are no files called `id_rsa` or `id_rsa.pub` on `~/.ssh` folder...how could I create these files?

Comment: You can create your SSH keys with the `ssh-keygen` command from the bash prompt. Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#step-1-create-your-ssh-keys).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nancy Xiong, however this partially solves the problem as I thought that the repo could be created directly from git bash command line into azure, Step 3 from link states that it is necessary to create a repo and when I ran `az repos create --name demo_repo`, this error arises `ClientRequestError: Page not found.  Operation returned a 404 status code`, even when ssh keys are created as bash returns  `remote: Shell access is not supported.` as the link stated.

Comment: Hi, please check my update, I use the Az cli command in git bash. It will automatically use the Azure account authentication, If you are using SSH keys, you just need to put the public key into the Azure Repos, it will be automatically authenticated with ssh method.

Comment: It runs perfectly until step 3, `ClientRequestError` returns from git bash command line even when I already created a new git repo on Azure Repos team page; I already updated the command line output on the question.

Comment: Do you run a git tool in windows? I suggest reinstalling or upgrading your git [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

Comment: The same error persists, I am starting to believe that Azure Devops does not currently support that functionality, I thought that it would be possible to complete such a task in Azure as in Github

Comment: I don't understand the thought because It seems no error on my side when run `az devops create` in git bash.

Comment: I followed instructions and in step 3, when I ran `az repos create --name  mywebapprepos` the terminal returns `ClientRequestError: 403 FORBIDDEN  Operation returned a 403 status code.`

Comment: Do you use an Azure account with `az login` to authenticate with Azure DevOps? If not, or if you are using a service principal with az login, you need to use a PAT token. `If you have already signed in with az login interactively or using user name and password, then you don't have to provide a token as az devops commands now support sign in through az login. However, service principal log in via az login isn't supported, in which case a PAT token is required.`Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows

Comment: I tried to do this, and command line returns me this: `Failed to authenticate using the supplied token.`, I already updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

> when I ran az repos create --name  mywebapprepos the terminal returns ClientRequestError: 403 FORBIDDEN  Operation returned a 403 status code.

According to this error message, I suggest you can try to log in Azure Devops using **Full Access PAT**(personal access tokens).

[image]

Here is a doc about [Creating PAT in Azure Devops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).

Then when you execute the `az devops login` , you could use the Full Access PAT as the Identity authentication method.

You can enter PAT in the next line.

Finally, you could try to run the `az repos create --name` again.

**Update:**

You can also try to use the following steps:

1.Create a file to save the PAT.

[image]

2.You could run the following command:

```
cat ado.pat | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/orgname
```

[image]

For more detailed information, you could refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/log-in-via-pat?view=azure-devops&tabs=windows#fetch-pat-from-a-file).

Comment: When I ran `az devops login --organization organization_url` and then the `PAT` it returns me the next error: `Failed to authenticate using the supplied token.`, even when I followed the instructions above...maybe I don't have manager credentials and I have to ask for them or something like that....

Comment: Hi @AlvaroMartinez. Please check my update and try to use the file to save the PAT.

Comment: Hey @Key Lu-MSFT, should I save the ado.pat file on local repo or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes. You need to save this file in the same folder where the command is executed. Then you could check if it could work

Comment: The error persists when I ran:  `cat ado.pat.txt | az devops login --organization org_url` (even I added ado.pat.txt to local repo) ; I tried to create an environmental variable on windows powershell by running `$env:AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT = 'xxxxxxxxxxx' ` and then `az devops login --organization org_url` but windows powershell don't let me paste the PAT....

Comment: Can you directly visit org and manually create repo on the UI？ If the PAT has enough access, it could login successfully. On the other hand, in powershell, since you have set the pat env, it will not ask you for the PAT again, it will directly use the PAT env. So in Powershell , can you login successfully?

Comment: Yes, I can do it manually without problem

Answer (score 1):

When you already install Git Bash and Azure CLI in Windows and want to run Azure CLI in git bash, you need to check the environment variable `PATH` if the path of the CLI is set in it. Like this:

[image]

If the CLI path is not in the environment variable `PATH`, you need to add it yourself like this:

```
export PATH=CLIPATH:$PATH
```

Check again and make sure the PATH is right to set. Then you  can run the az command like this:

[image]

Because the executable program in that path name `az.cmd`. So if you want to use the command `az` instead the `az.cmd`, you need to set the alias for it like this:

[image]

When all things is ok, you can run the Azure CLI command as you expect:

[image]

Then here is the screenshot of the test on my side for the repos:

[image]

Hope all the above will help you solve the issue. And if you have more questions about this issue, please let me know.

Comment: Hey @Charles Xu, when I ran `az repos list -o table` the command line output was: `ClientRequestError: Page not found.  Operation returned a 404 status code.`,

Comment: @AlvaroMartinez Do you set the DevOps to configure with command `az DevOps configure` and does the account you log in for Azure CLI is the same as the acount of the DevOps?

Comment: Hey @Charles Xu, thanks for your response, I ran `az Devops configure` and it runs without any error, however the problem `az login` still exists; would be great to know how to check if log in for Azure CLI is the same as the Devops account